# How to center a ImageView vertically in its parent?

Tags: java, android

My layout design is a TextView with long text and a ImageView to the right of the TextView. I want to center the ImageView in its parent vertically, so I used android:layout_centerVertical="true", but it turned out that the ImageView was aligned to the bottom of its parent. If I don't use layout_centerVertical property, the ImageView will be aligned to the top of its parent. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/t3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:scaleType="centerInside" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long sentence"
        android:textColor="#231ACC" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/t3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 41):

Try `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

Comment: It should be `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` instead.

Comment: papaiatis is right, use "layout_gravity" and make sure NOT to mix up          android:gravity="center"
and android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: layout_gravity is not appropriate for RelativeLayout. You should use keep android:layout_centerVertical="true" and make sure android:layout_height=fill_parent

Comment: @erin whats wrong with wrap_content? Why fill_parent?

Answer (score 25):

Add this xml attribute to the child you wish to center within it's parent:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

This will center it vertically/horizontally.

Comment: @KVISH this is true.  As in the OP's question, the parent has to be a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 11):

change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` of RelativeLayout and add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to TextView, it will work like charm.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something that would work in a RelativeLayout!

Comment: layout_gravity is a property of LinearLayout, not RelativeLayout.  There is no need to wrap the ImageView in a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a `LinearLayout` with `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `fill_parent` and gravity set to `vertical_center`.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/input_field"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Left Aligned"/>
               <EditText  
            android:id="@+id/input_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Right Aligned"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your XML file?

Comment: The code sample is from something I was working on a couple of days ago where I needed to horizontally and vertically center a row of text input fields. The task you describe sounds similar.

Comment: In my example, it is different. I want the size of the ImageView to the right of the TextView to be exact the size of the picture the ImageView contains. So your example doesn't work for my case.

Answer (score 3):

This will put your image to the vertical center of it's parent:

`android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

Demo:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="Application icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this:

> android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while building in Android Studio 4.2.1 and the solution after some tinkering was:

```
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

this way, constraining to both sides automatically centers the widget and satisfies the need for constraints. The same is true when centering vertically, by using:

```
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```